# Find most common combination between pairs

Tags: r, list, similarity, recommendation-engine

I have a list of events and guests who have attended these events. Like so but a much bigger file:

```
event       guests
birthday    John Doe
birthday    Jane Doe
birthday    Mark White
wedding     John Doe
wedding     Jane Doe
wedding     Matthew Green
bar mitzvah Janet Black
bar mitzvah John Doe
bar mitzvah Jane Doe
bar mitzvah William Hill
retirement  Janet Black
retirement  Matthew Green
```

I want to find the most common combination of two guests who attend the most events together. So in this example, the answer should be `John Doe` and `Jane Doe` attend the most events together because they have both attended three of the same events. The output should be a list of these pairs.

Where do I even start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly different approach from a social networks/matrix algebra point of view:

Your data describes links between individuals by shared membership. This is an affiliation matrix and we can compute the matrix of connections between individuals $i$ and $j$ as follows:

```
# Load as a data frame
df <- data.frame(event = c(rep("birthday", 3), 
                           rep("wedding", 3), 
                           rep("bar mitzvah", 4), 
                           rep("retirement", 2)), 
                  guests = c("John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Mark White", 
                             "John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Matthew Green",   
                              "Janet Black", "John Doe", "Jane Doe",
                              "William Hill", "Janet Black", "Matthew Green"))

# You can represent who attended which event as a matrix
M <- table(df$guests, df$event)
# Now we can compute how many times each individual appeared at an
# event with another with a simple matrix product
admat <- M %*% t(M)
admat


  ##################Jane Doe Janet Black John Doe Mark White Matthew Green William Hill
  #Jane Doe             3           1        3          1             1            1
  #Janet Black          1           2        1          0             1            1
  #John Doe             3           1        3          1             1            1
  #Mark White           1           0        1          1             0            0
  #Matthew Green        1           1        1          0             2            0
  #William Hill         1           1        1          0             0            1
```

Now we want to get rid of the diagonal of the matrix (which tells us how many events each individual attended) and one of the two triangles of the matrix which contains redundant information.

```
diag(admat) <- 0
admat[upper.tri(admat)] <- 0
```

Now we just want to convert to a format you might prefer. I'll use the `melt` function in the reshape2 library.

```
library(reshape2)
dfmatches <- unique(melt(admat))
# Drop all the zero matches
dfmatches <- dfmatches[dfmatches$value !=0,]
# order it descending
dfmatches <- dfmatches[order(-dfmatches$value),]
dfmatches

#            Var1        Var2 value
#3       John Doe    Jane Doe     3
#2    Janet Black    Jane Doe     1
#4     Mark White    Jane Doe     1
#5  Matthew Green    Jane Doe     1
#6   William Hill    Jane Doe     1
#9       John Doe Janet Black     1
#11 Matthew Green Janet Black     1
#12  William Hill Janet Black     1
#16    Mark White    John Doe     1
#17 Matthew Green    John Doe     1
#18  William Hill    John Doe     1
```

Obviously you could tidy the output up by renaming the variables of interest etc.

This general approach -- by which I mean recognizing that your data describes a social network -- might be of interest to you for further analysis (for instance, maybe people are meaningfully linked if they go to parties with a lot of the same people, even if not with each other). If your data set is really big you can make the matrix algebra a little faster by using sparse matrices, or by loading the igraph package and working with the functions there for declaring social networks.

Comment: very nice approach!

Answer (score 3):

From your statement "attend the most events together" I will assume that by similarity you mean `intersect`.

You can find intersect between events ~ names using following code:

```
# All names that we have
nameAll <- unique(df$guests)
# Length of names vector
N <- length(nameAll)

# Function to find intersect between names
getSimilarity <- function(nameA, nameB, type = "intersect") {
    # Subset events for name A
    eventA <- subset(df, guests == nameA)$event
    # Subset events for name B
    eventB <- subset(df, guests == nameB)$event
    # Fint intersect length between events
    if (type == "intersect") {
        res <- length(intersect(eventA, eventB))
    }
    # Find Jaccard index between events
    if (type == "JC") {
        res <- length(intersect(eventA, eventB)) / length(union(eventA, eventB))
    }
    # Return result
    return(data.frame(type, value = res, nameA, nameB))
}

# Iterate over all possible combinations
# Using double loop for simpler representation    
result <- list()
for(i in 1:(N-1)) {
    for(j in (i+1):N) {
        result[[length(result) + 1]] <- getSimilarity(nameAll[i], nameAll[j])
    }
}
# Transform result to data.frame and order by similarity 
result <- do.call(rbind, result)
# Showing top 5 pairs
head(result[with(result, order(-value)), ])
```

> ```
>        type value    nameA         nameB
> 1 intersect     3 John Doe      Jane Doe
> 2 intersect     1 John Doe    Mark White
> 3 intersect     1 John Doe Matthew Green
> 4 intersect     1 John Doe   Janet Black
> 5 intersect     1 John Doe  William Hill
> ```

[Jaccard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) also gives the same result:

> ```
>    type     value       nameA        nameB
> 1    JC 1.0000000    John Doe     Jane Doe
> 15   JC 0.5000000 Janet Black William Hill
> 2    JC 0.3333333    John Doe   Mark White
> 5    JC 0.3333333    John Doe William Hill
> 6    JC 0.3333333    Jane Doe   Mark White
> ```

---

Data (`df`):

```
structure(list(event = c("birthday", "birthday", "birthday", 
"wedding", "wedding", "wedding", "bar mitzvah", "bar mitzvah", 
"bar mitzvah", "bar mitzvah", "retirement", "retirement"), guests = c("John Doe", 
"Jane Doe", "Mark White", "John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Matthew Green", 
"Janet Black", "John Doe", "Jane Doe", "William Hill", "Janet Black", 
"Matthew Green")), .Names = c("event", "guests"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answers here are great. I just what to share some thoughts. If you are working on a large datasets, with many guests or many events. Many conditions are possible. For example, more than two guests both went to the same events the most, or two groups of guests went two different events, but the total counts are the same. If that is the case, finding the top two guests may not be sufficient.

Here I want to demonstrate the use the hierarchical clustering to find the guests or groups that are similar.

We can first construct a matrix with 1 and 0, whereas 1 means attendance and 0 means no attendance.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(vegan)

dat_m <- dat %>%
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  spread(event, value, fill = 0) %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = "guests") %>%
  as.matrix()

dat_m
#               bar mitzvah birthday retirement wedding
# Jane Doe                1        1          0       1
# Janet Black             1        0          1       0
# John Doe                1        1          0       1
# Mark White              0        1          0       0
# Matthew Green           0        0          1       1
# William Hill            1        0          0       0
```

We can then calculate the distance of each guest. Notice that I used the `vegdist` function from the `vegan` package and set the `binary = TRUE` because we are working on binary data.

```
dat_dist <- vegdist(dat_m, binary = TRUE)

dat_dist
#                Jane Doe Janet Black  John Doe Mark White Matthew Green
# Janet Black   0.6000000                                               
# John Doe      0.0000000   0.6000000                                   
# Mark White    0.5000000   1.0000000 0.5000000                         
# Matthew Green 0.6000000   0.5000000 0.6000000  1.0000000              
# William Hill  0.5000000   0.3333333 0.5000000  1.0000000     1.0000000
```

And then we can conduct hierarchical clustering and view the results.

```
hc <- hclust(dat_dist)
plot(hc)
```

[image]

Based on the dendrogram, `Jane Doe` and `John Doe` are the most similar and, as a group, they are the most different than the others.

We can also check that `Jane Doe` and `John Doe` attended the highest event number. So we know we can select these two.

```
rowSums(dat_m)
# Jane Doe   Janet Black      John Doe    Mark White Matthew Green  William Hill 
#        3             2             3             1             2             1
```

Again I think others' answers are more straightforward and give you the output for this example dataset, but if you are working on a larger dataset. Hierarchical Clustering could be a choice.